# Need help converting "sassy" to "$a55y" using a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Any s at the beginning of the word should be converted to a $.

Any s inside the word should be converted to a 5.

Comment: i know i'm going to regret asking, but "Why?"

Comment: You could do two passes, replacing " s" (space - s) with "$" the first time and then "s" with "5" the second...

Comment: @Cephron you probably mean `/\bs/` for word break, not a space. space-s won't match the start of input among other things.

Comment: @Mitch 2 l33t3n up h1z $a55ine55.

Answer (score 3):

To match an `s` at the start of the word, use `\b` to match word boundaries <s>and `\w` to match alphanumerics:</s>

```
/\bs\w/
```

*(as @Matthew points out, the `\w` is really superfluous:)*

```
/\bs/
```

Once you've replaced all `s` at the start of a word, then the only remaining ones are inside the word (I'm assuming that you also want to replace `s` at the end of a word with `5`) so you can simply use

```
/s/
```

---

For completeness, here's how to put it all together (I'm going to assume JavaScript):

```
function pimpMyEsses(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\bs/gi, '$').replace(/s/gi, '5');
}

console.log(pimpMyEsses('slither quantum Sassy. arcades'));
// > "$lither quantum $a55y. arcade5"
```

Comment: Why use `\w`? What if the 'word' is simply `"s"`?

Comment: That's a valid point. I could use `\B` instead but a 1-character word is a corner case that the OP hasn't specified for.

Comment: My question is more "Why bother specifying that something has to follow an initial `s` at all? For your example all we care about is replacing the initial 's', yes?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language it may be possible to capture the substitutions with a single regular expression and replace them procedurally.  Here's a PHP example:

```
<?php

$word = 'sassy';
preg_match_all('/\b(s)|([^s]+)|(s)/', $word, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

/* captures:
 *   $matches = array(
 *      array('s','s'),
 *      array('a','','a'),
 *      array('s','','','s'),
 *      array('s','','','s'),
 *      array('y','','y')
 *    )
 */

$newword = '';
foreach ($matches as $m){
    if ($m[1]) $newword .= '$';       # leading s   --> $
    elseif ($m[2]) $newword .= $m[2]; # not an s    --> as-is
    else $newword .= '5';             # any other s --> 5
}
echo $newword;
```

Because I've used `\b` to match a word-boundary before the *"leading s"*, the string `'sassy socks'` becomes `'$a55y $ock5'`

If you want only the s at the start of "sassy" to become a $, change the regular expression to:

```
'/^(s)|([^s]+)|(s)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

- `/^(s)/` to select only the first "s";
- `/(?:[^s])(?:(s)[^s]*)+` to select all other "s". Note that the first character will be skipped (which is independent of);

  - **Explain**:
    ignore first character;
    Repeat one or more: get a "s" and ignore others character that not "s";

Next step: you need to determinate what language you will use.

Comment: @David Your second example need a quantifier (`+`) otherwise it'll only select an s if it is in the second position.

Comment: `/^(s)/` will select only an `s` at the start of the input, not the start of a word.

Comment: @David `.s` will still match ` s` and hit the first character (if it hadn't already been replaced), so it still seems wrong to me.

Comment: @Matt the problem is that don't exists examples. I don't know exactly what @Coffee wants.

Comment: @David A space is `^s` too, so... :D

Comment: @Matthew haha, yeap. But I consider all input. If he wants, he need to trim the string before pass, or regex it too.

Comment: Too much :/ I really don't think that regex is the best option for this case.

Comment: If you just make two separate (chained) `replace()`s it's really simple. See my answer.